# What are the authors and textbooks that praise mathematical beauty the most?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

What are some good authors - or textbooks itself - of mathematics textbooks that focus on constructing elegant theorems, proofs, et cetera?

One example of author that writes that way would probably (and I say probably because I used one of his books  only as a supplement, not as the main text) be Paul Halmos.

I am looking for real analysis, algebra and theory of numbers authors and textbooks, mainly.

Any suggestions?

It can also be authors/textbooks of physics books, but they must include mathematics teaching in their books. Also it doesn't have to be a very good book to study, I intend to use it as a way for recreational activities.

Comment: I like Polya (classic) and Tao.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Proofs from the Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK) by Aigner & Ziegler.